# Concat a column's value with other column's lead() value in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table like the below:

```
+---------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------+
|       prompt        |        answer                      | step_timestamp      | 
+---------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------+
| hi Lary             |                                    | 2022-04-04 10:00:00 |
| how are you?        |                                    | 2022-04-04 10:02:00 |
| how is your pet?    |I am fine                           | 2022-04-04 10:05:00 |
| what is your hobby? |my pet is good                      | 2022-04-04 10:15:00 | 
| ok thanks           |football                            | 2022-04-04 10:25:00 | 
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------
```

The answer has to match with the prompt of the previous row.
Expected result :

```
hi Lary, how are you?I am fine. how is your pet?my pet is good. what is your hobby? football. ok thanks
```

For this I have done this

```
WITH SUPER AS(
SELECT call_id, group_concat(tall,'\t') as dialog_text,
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tall,call_id
                             ORDER BY step_timestamp ASC) AS rn,call_id,tall
   FROM
     (SELECT  call_id,step_timestamp, concat(prompt,':',lead(answer) over(PARTITION BY call_id,step_timestamp order by step_timestamp asc)) tall
      FROM db.table
      ORDER BY step_timestamp ASC
      limit 100000000
)as inq
      ORDER BY step_timestamp ASC
      limit 100000000
   ) b
WHERE rn =1
GROUP BY call_id,call_ani
)select distinct call_id, dialog_text
from super;
```

But it does not work as expecting. For example some times I have something like this:

```
hi lary, how are you?I am fine. how is your pet?my pet is good. how is your pet?I am fine. what is your hobby? football. ok thanks
```

Comment: You probably know the reason. `group_concat()` in impala doesnt maintain order by. Now even if you put `limit 10000000`, it may not put all rows into same node to ensure ordered concat.

Answer (score 0):

You probably know the reason already. group_concat() in impala doesnt maintain order by. Now even if you put limit 10000000, it may not put all rows into same node to ensure ordered concat.
Use hive `collect_list()`.

I couldnt find relevance of your rownumber() so i removed it to keep the solution simple. Please test below code with your original data and then add rownumber if needed.

```
select
  id call_id,  
  concat( concat_ws(',', min(g)) ) dialog_text
from
  (
    select
      s.id, 
      --use collect list to cooncat all dialogues in order of timestamp.
      collect_list(s.tall) over (partition by s.id order by s.step_timestamp desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) g 
    from
      ( 
      SELECT  call_id id,step_timestamp, 
      concat(prompt,':',lead(answer) over(PARTITION BY call_id,step_timestamp order by step_timestamp asc)) tall
      FROM db.table -- This it main data
      ) s
  ) gs 
-- Need to group by 'id' since we have duplicate collect_list values
group by  id
```